# Flyway script is not executed using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

I had the problem that all or some of my migration scripts are not executed by Flyway. I'm using Spring Boot and I have configured Flyway within the application.properties file.
The configuration includes a `basic` and a `migration` directory. Both directories are divided into common and vendor-specific directories (eg. flyway/migrate/POSTGRESQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least it was a case-(in)sensitive problem. The vendor-specific directories where created by a Mac-user and have been written in upper case letters (eg. POSTGRESQL), while Flyway uses lower case letters (eg. flyway/migrate/{vendor} which translates to flyway/migrate/postgresql). This is not a problem on MacOSX or Windows, but on my Linux machine.

I hope this helps if someone faces the same problem.